# Uninstalling Python after manually moving it to a different drive

Tags: python, windows, uninstallation

I originally installed Python on drive D. At some point I manually moved everything from drive D to C so that I can delete the partition for drive D (in retrospect, bad idea). Now I am unable to uninstall Python since the installation still thinks it's located on drive D.

Is there anyway to tell Python it's installed on drive C now? Or maybe a way to force the uninstallation?

[This is the error I got when trying to uninstall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJj8M.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to change all values in the registry manually. There are a number of ways to trick the installer to clean up the registry for you.
One of them is to plug in an USB storage drive and make it mount under "D:".
You can manipulate drive letters in Control panel under computer management, which is found in Administrative Tools, which can be found in different places according to your Windows version. Administrative Tools may also be available through the start menu.

You mount something, a network drive, or USB drive or virtual drive or whatever under "D:", you copy-paste your Python folder you manually moved before there, under the same name you used before, and you start the installer/uninstaller. After uninstall, your registry is clean, and your Python on "C:" and your old folder name, free.
If you already removed the copy on "C:", run the Python installer, point it to "D:" and when it asks whether you want to overwrite the existing Python, just do it. After installation, uninstall it.

Note: If you installed some libraries including binaries that have to add something to the registry, like pywintypes, go to your Python's directory (in one you installed the library under, if you installed them before moving, then in the newly created folder, otherwise on the drive "C:"), there you will find individual uninstallers for each of them. E.g. Removepywin32.exe, Removepy2exe.exe, Removetwain.exe ... You will find practically an uninstaller for each lib you installed using a binary installer instead of pip or manual installation. Most of them do not have to be run in order to clean up the registry, but some do. The Python uninstaller should be able to run them automatically, but what is safe is safe.

This way of uninstall I know will work without trying it first, so that's what I wrote. It is a bit of work, but well, you shouldn't have moved Python so forcefully before.
What you do when you want to do it is, make a backup of Python's folder (copy-paste somewhere else), then uninstall it. Then install the fresh version wherever you want (same version as the one you removed), then overwrite the fresh installed folder with your old one. If you have libraries installed that need registry entries you have to reinstall them in order for them to work properly. But essentially this is the procedure that always works.

Comment: The USB trick is a great idea, I hadn't thought of it. Anyway, I shouldn't have manually moved Python to a different drive, but I've learned my lesson.

Comment: Wow this really saved me. I had a D:/ drive crap out on me and python wouldn't let me install the same version on the other drive, nor uninstall it (because it couldn't find D:) but this appears to have fixed everything and I can get a fresh install on C:. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to change the path to the new driver and everything will work fine
https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/ follow the **Manually add Python to Windows Path** part in this article till you reach the old path and replace it with the new one , after try the command

```
  pip list
```

in the command prompt to get all the packages installed if it worked then now your windows is recognizing which driver python installed in.
Restart everything after and do the uninstallation safely

Answer (score 0):

Changing the PATH environment variable was not enough. I ended up changing every registry value that had D: to C: under Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore.

Answer (score 0):

- Click Start and type CMD.
- Right Click the Command Prompt Icon and click Run as Administrator
- In command prompt, type:
  subst D: C:\
- Press Enter.
  This should make your uninstallations work now. Please let me know if you need further advice! Thanks!